# How to extract noise distribution of an image and apply it to aonther image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

Question about **synthetic images to simulate documents scanned by scanner or shot by cameras**, *using python*.
I want to **generate** images with simlar distribution noise but not exactly the same background of original images. I'm confused about:

1. How to extract the noise distribution of an image,
2. and how to apply it to another image.